R: More efficent way to create a new data frame column containing the maximum value from a string
Example DF:
country <- c('Australia', 'Italy', 'Peru', 'China')
score <- c("0.091", "0.413,.", "-", "0.102,0.102,0.102,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.")
country_scores <- data.frame(country, score)

Each entry of score can have any number of comma separated values or a "-" for no data. I am looking to extract the largest value in the string and test whether it meets a certain threshold. I tried a solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65121200/8621123 but the solution is very slow (at least 8 minutes) on my data frame of 1.3 million rows and 186 columns:
library(tidyverse)

country_scores %>%
  mutate(scores = str_extract_all(score, '\\d+(\\.\\d+)?'), 
         score_max = map_dbl(new, ~max(as.numeric(.x))))


See if this data.table approach works for your data
library(data.table)

setDT(country_scores)

country_scores[, max_score := sapply(strsplit(score, ", *"), \(x) 
  last(sort(as.numeric(x[grepl("^\\d+\\.*\\d+$", x)])))[1])]

output
     country                             score max_score
      <char>                            <char>     <num>
1: Australia                             0.091     0.091
2:     Italy                           0.413,.     0.413
3:      Peru                                 -        NA
4:     China 0.102,0.102,0.102,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.     0.102

Or with max,a little faster, but needs to suppressWarnings and puts Inf per default.
suppressWarnings(
  country_scores[, max_score := sapply(strsplit(score, ", *"), \(x) 
    max(as.numeric(x[grepl("^\\d+\\.*\\d+$", x)])))])

Note that you can always turn the data back to a base dataframe with setDF(country_scores)
A little benchmark
All single core, since on Intel Mac. data.table will profit from multi core systems and provide more speed up on Linux and Windows (or OpenMP-enabled Mac). country_scores extended to 100,000 all unique lines.
Unit: seconds
            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max
      dplyR_orig 31.888486 32.514975 33.326635 33.351345 34.236091 34.74258
  dplyR_slicemax 43.597723 44.021222 45.348425 45.635679 46.019922 47.77643
 data.table_sort 17.008924 17.382891 17.658448 17.589783 17.845170 18.49448
  data.table_max  7.556219  7.585715  7.648081  7.631336  7.662826  7.84545
 neval  cld
    10 a   
    10  b  
    10   c 
    10    d


library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  dplyR_orig = {suppressWarnings(country_scores %>% 
       mutate(scores = str_extract_all(score, '\\d+(\\.\\d+)?'), 
              score_max = purrr::map_dbl(scores, ~max(as.numeric(.x)))))},
  dplyR_slicemax = {suppressWarnings(country_scores %>% 
       separate_longer_delim(score, ",") %>% 
       slice_max(as.numeric(score), with_ties = F, by = country))},
  data.table_sort = {setDT(country_scores); 
     country_scores[, max_score := sapply(strsplit(score, ", *"), \(x) 
       data.table::last(sort(as.numeric(x[grepl("^\\d+\\.*\\d+$", x)])))[1])]},
  data.table_max = {setDT(country_scores); 
     suppressWarnings(country_scores[, max_score := sapply(strsplit(score, ", *"), \(x) 
       max(as.numeric(x[grepl("^\\d+\\.*\\d+$", x)])))])}, times=10)


An alternative tidyverse approach using separate_longer_delim and slice_max which is x10 faster than using str_extract_all and map_dbl.
(data.table is also a great option.)
library(tidyverse)

country <- c("Australia", "Italy", "Peru", "China")
score <- c("0.091", "0.413,.", "-", "0.102,0.102,0.102,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,z")
country_scores <- data.frame(country, score)

# Original
bench::mark(
  original <- suppressWarnings(country_scores %>%
    mutate(
      scores = str_extract_all(score, "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"),
      score_max = map_dbl(scores, ~ max(as.numeric(.x)))
    ))
)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   expression                             min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                          <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 original <- suppressWarnings(count… 17.6ms 17.9ms      54.8    7.72MB     64.6

original
#>     country                             score              scores score_max
#> 1 Australia                             0.091               0.091     0.091
#> 2     Italy                           0.413,.               0.413     0.413
#> 3      Peru                                 -                          -Inf
#> 4     China 0.102,0.102,0.102,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,z 0.102, 0.102, 0.102     0.102

# Separate and slice
bench::mark(
  slice <- suppressWarnings(country_scores |>
    separate_longer_delim(score, ",") |>
    slice_max(as.numeric(score), with_ties = F, by = country))
)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   expression                             min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                          <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 slice <- suppressWarnings(slice_ma… 1.58ms 1.63ms      604.    1.39MB     15.8

slice
#>     country score
#> 1 Australia 0.091
#> 2     Italy 0.413
#> 3      Peru     -
#> 4     China 0.102

# Slower on a toy dataset, but may be worth
# also experimenting with on a much larger file
library(multidplyr)
cluster <- new_cluster(10)

country_scores |> 
  separate_longer_delim(score, ",") |>
  group_by(country) |> 
  partition(cluster) |> 
  summarise(score_max = max(as.numeric(score), na.rm = TRUE)) |> 
  collect()

Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.1.0

Careful with by = country since this also merges rows with same country codes. The original approach does not mention if duplicates exist but goes row by row without grouping hence the original result and source will have equal row count.

Yes, depends on their intent. They could group by country if their intent is a country max which, in the absence of other variables, seemed like it might be the intent.
